# converting json string to MatOfKeyPoint object in python

Tags: python, json, opencv

i calculate the keypoints of an image using ORB detector in android and convert json string and i need to send it a server running on python .the json string converted on android device looks something like

```
[     
{"class_id":-1,"x":208.0,"y":2492.0,"size":31.0,"angle":312.0059,"octave":0,"response":1.2840814E-4},
{"class_id":-1,"x":114.0,"y":1898.0,"size":31.0,"angle":312.86102,"octave":0,"response":1.4190769E-4},
{"class_id":-1,"x":1519.0,"y":701.0,"size":31.0,"angle":252.71167,"octave":0,"response":7.2368234E-4},
...
]
```

i am unable to convert it to MatOfKeyPoint from this string using python

the code i am using in  is

```
res = json.loads((s).decode("utf-8") )
size = len(res) 
kpArray = [dict() for x in range(0,size)]
for x1 in xrange(0,size):
#print(type(res[x1]['x']))
kpArray[x1]['pt'] = (res[x1]['x'],res[x1]['y'])
kpArray[x1]['angle'] = res[x1]['angle']
kpArray[x1]['class_id'] = res[x1]['class_id']
kpArray[x1]['size'] = res[x1]['size']
kpArray[x1]['angle'] = res[x1]['angle']
kpArray[x1]['octave'] = res[x1]['octave']
kpArray[x1]['response'] = res[x1]['response']
```

Comment: What error are you getting?What is your expected output?

Comment: after converting i am trying to plot key points on images using drawKeyPoints but it is saying give a valid keypoint type as argument